# make routes for a subdir in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, subdirectory

I use a [Vue Starter Template](https://github.com/web2033/vite-vue3-tailwind-starter):

#### `Vite + Vue 3 + Tailwind CSS (starter) ⚡`

- [Tailwind CSS v3.0.0-alpha ⚠](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/releases/tag/v3.0.0-alpha.1)
- [Vue Router 4.x](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next)

The App should run in a subdirectory like: `domain.com/VueApp` and i followd the [manpage of router vuejs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) to add a `base`like this:

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    base: '/VueApp/',
    routes,
})
```

But the `<router-links>` still ignore that base entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don´t know if I understood you correctly, but if you want the url have `/VueApp/` in it, you need to change it for the `createWebHistory()`. Like this:

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory('/VueApp/'),
    base: '/VueApp/',
    routes,
})
```

`base` declares where your app is located at the domain, but still would run without the given path.

Comment: You did and now it works :-)